# Updating a Column in Cassandra based on Where Clause

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I have a very simple table

```
cqlsh:hell> describe columnfamily info ;

CREATE TABLE info (
  nos int,
  value map<text, text>,
  PRIMARY KEY (nos)
)
```

The following is the query where I am trying to update the value .

```
update info set value = {'count' : '0' , 'onget' :  'function onget(value,count) { count++ ; return {"value": value, "count":count} ; }' } where nos  <= 1000 ;
Bad Request: Invalid operator LTE for PRIMARY KEY part nos
```

I use any operator for specifying the constraint . It complains saying invalid operator. I am not sure what I am doing wrong in here , according to cassandra 3.0 cql doc, there are similar update queries.

The following is my version

```
[cqlsh 4.1.0 | Cassandra 2.0.3 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.38.0]
```

I have no idea , whats going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried just using '=' ?

The first predicate of the where clause has to uniquely identify the partition key. In your case, since the primary key is only one column the partition key == the primary key.

Comment: '=' works just fine. Any other operator throws me an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is really in my comment, but it needs a bit of elaboration. To restate from the comment...

The first predicate of the where clause has to uniquely identify the partition key. In your case, since the primary key is only one column the partition key == the primary key.

Cassandra can't do range scans over partitions. In the language of CQL, a partition is a potentially wide storage row that is uniquely identified by a key. In this case, the values in your nos column. The values of the partition keys are hashed into tokens which explicitly identify where that data lives in the cluster. Since that hash has no order to it, Cassandra cannot use any operator other than equality to route a statement to the correct destination. This isn't a primary key index that could potentially be updated, it is the fundamental partitioning mechanism in Cassandra. So, you can't use inequality operators as the first clause of a predicate. You can use them in subsequent clauses because the partition has been identified and now you're dealing with an ordered set of columns.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use non-equal condition on the partition key (`nos` is your partition key).

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#selectWhere

Comment: Thats such a bummer! is there any other alternative to solve this problem.

Comment: You need to write your table schema to answer your queries. "Model your queries" is the mantra of C*. When your query doesn't fit your schema it means you need either a different table (possibly duplicating information) or a change in your current schema.

Answer (score -1):

Cassandra currently does not support user defined functions inside a query such as the following.

```
update info set value = {'count' : '0' , 'onget' :  'function onget(value,count) { count++ ; return {"value": value, "count":count} ; }' } where nos  <= 1000 ;
```

First, can you push this `onget` function into the application layer? You can first query all the rows which nos < 1000. Then increment rows those via some batch query.

Otherwise, you can use a counter column for `nos`, not a int data type. Notice though, you cannot mix `map` data type with counter column families unless the non-counter columns are part of a composite key.

Also, you probably doe not want to have `nos`, a column that changes value as the primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE info (
  id UUID,
  value map<text, text>,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) 

CREATE TABLE nos_counter (
  info_id UUID,
  nos COUNTER,
  PRIMARY KEY (info_id)
)
```

Now you can update the nos counter like this.

```
update info set nos = nos + 1 where info_id = 'SOME_UUID';
```

Comment: But why Cant I update a coloumn based on primary key ? Its pretty intuitive from MySQL perspective. The onget function is just a random text , its not meant to be a code per se.

Comment: Primary keys are indexed. Being that if you update the primary key value `nos`, you would have to update the index; which is most likely a costly operation. Also, the primary key may also determine where the data is persisted/replicated across the cluster.

Comment: The Primary key actually indicates which node the data is located on so inequality queries require contacting multiple nodes and accessing data in a way inefficient to the way C* operates. This is why this type of query is disabled in C*. "Primary Keys are not Indexed" in the relational sense.

Currently, there is no method for passing arbitrary functions so C* so that suggestion is misleading as well. 

Even though example is actually a good solution (new schema), a lot of the additional information is misleading or only appropriate for Relational systems.

Comment: That query with the function is copy paste from the OP's question. Made more clear that it is not a proper query. And yes the primary keys are not really index, in the traditional sense, but requests are routed via [consistent hashing](http://goo.gl/koRuAN) since it is using a peer-to-peer architecture.